# Django model form save, 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

I have this error:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py:

```
def add_profile(request):
    user = request.user.id
    form = ProfileForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: @catherine but I exclude `user` in my form. I want to save user from `user = request.user.id`

Comment: user = request.user.id should be user = request.user and then try profile = form.save(commit=False) profile.user = user profile.save()

Comment: That's not the proper way to save the id. And what you have did for saving user = request.user.id, has no effect. Even you use user.save() it's pointing to none

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_profile(request):
    save_user = Profile(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=save_user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```